# How can I set Fullcalendar options dynamically

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How can I set the `minTime` and `maxTime` options after the calendar is created?

I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'minTime', 7);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

Comment: I don't know if FC can reinitialize with different options; in my app I just do `window.location.reload()` after changing the min/maxTime...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done without recreating the calendar.

**Update:**
Can be done in v 2.9: See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38299511/628699)

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if it is still relevant but I can change the options with the following statement:

example for selectable:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.selectable = false;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); // rerender to see visual changes
```

Though it's not dynamically but at least you don't have to destroy the whole calendar and refetch your events :-)

Comment: Many thanks, this workaround is awesome. It works on fullcalendar v2 as well, and I just would like to add that to get the options changes to take visible effect call: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');`

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 4):

This way you can change as many calendar options you like:

```
// save the calendar options in a variable
var calendarOptions = $('#calendar')
     .fullCalendar('getView')
     .options;

// make your changes to the calendar options
// I wanted to change the slotDuration
calendarOptions.slotDuration = '00:20:00';

// destroy the calendar
$('#calendar')
     .fullCalendar('destroy');

//Lets load the calendar with the new options
$('#calendar')
     .fullCalendar(calendarOptions);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks

Comment: @DuyHoang please check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39360621/4742733.  It seems `FullCalendar v3` is out and the answer here is more efficient.

Comment: I wanna change minTime and maxTime after changing date (using next, back,today... buttons) What is the best place that i can put code `$('#cc-calendar')
  .fullCalendar('option','minTime','00:10:00');`  ?

Comment: @DuyHoang you will have to work with the `callback function` >> `viewRender(callback)` >> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/.  So when a view is `rendered` after you click `next,back,today` buttons, this function will be called and you can execute your line of code within that function.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality has been officially release in v2.9.0: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/

Answer (score 2):

There's an open issue for this functionality here:

https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293

Answer (score 1):

just me dude's answer is actually the only way I found myself.

This is just an addendum to this former answer : 
If you want to change the editable option, which is very useful if you want to lock the events for asking confirmation on a change before updating your database, it's a little more tricky. In case it can save some time to someone I dump the code:

```
var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
view.calendar.options.editable = false;
view.calendar.overrides.editable = false;
view.calendar.viewSpecCache.month.options.editable = false;
view.calendar.viewSpecCache.agendaWeek.options.editable = false;
view.calendar.viewSpecCache.agendaDay.options.editable = false;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

You obviously change all those false to true to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

This code just did fine for me. Call this function anywhere and pass as many custom variables to it, but don't forget to destroy the previous calendar first

```
function initializeCalendar( timeIntervalCustom ) {
  $('#calendar'+id).fullCalendar({
  slotMinutes: timeIntervalCustom,

});                       

}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar("destroy");
initializeCalendar(10);
```