# Setting the default click selection highlighting in FullCalendar issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with the grid set to 1/2 hour intervals (slotMinutes set to 30 minutes). I want the default click selection to be for a minimum of 1 hour events, but I want the start times to be in 30-minute increments. In other words, I don't want the user to be able to highlight any time slot that is less than an hour, but I want them to be able to highlight 1-hour slots beginning either on the hour or half-hour (i.e.: 1:30 - 2:30).

If I set the snapMinutes to 60, this solves the first part by not letting them highlight anything less than 1 hour. However, it won't let the user select 1-hour slots that do not fall exactly within an even hour (i.e.: it will allow selection of 1:00-2:00 but not 1:30-2:30). Is there any way I can achieve this?

Here is the calendar I'm using (CoffeeScript)

```
options = {
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    defaultEventMinutes: 60
    selectable: true
    selectHelper: true
    eventTextColor: 'black'
    allDayDefault: false
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today'
        center: ''
        right: 'title'
    }
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy'
        week: "MMM d[, yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d, yyyy}"
        day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
    }
    ignoreTimezone: true
    slotMinutes: 30
    snapMinutes: 60
}
elm.fullCalendar(options)
```

Here is a JSFiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lcrees/9f82c/

The second part of my question is that I want to be able to set the default minimum click selection above dynamically. From this issue it looks like I can't update the snapMinutes option dynamically without destroying and recreating the calendar:
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293
Any other suggestions? 
Lorill

Comment: On SO you usually need to show a first attempt; have you tried to code this up yourself yet? If so go ahead and post the relevant code. Otherwise, this question is far too broad.

Comment: Hi Teeg, I've added the code I'm using for the calendar.

Comment: Thanks user2821493 (if that is your real name...). I can't answer this myself as I've never used this library, but just looking at the documentation, I think you're right about snapMinutes, but I don't think there's a direct option to do the other part you want. I think you might need to make use of one of the callbacks, like maybe `eventDrop` or `eventDragStop` or something; basically whichever callback will give you custom control over the event dragging.

Comment: Additionally, regarding the dynamic part, again I can't say for certain, but unless they have some kind of setter method for that option, it wouldn't surprise me if you had to destroy and reset. Again , I would take a look at some of the callbacks, and worst case scenario, maybe see if you can extend the fullcalendar object (of course, that's getting in to monkey patching...which may or may not be a good use of time). That's my 2-cents; hopefully you get some actual answers.

Comment: I don't see any FullCalendar callback that can intercept the mousedown event of the selection of a new event. `dayClick` is the closest it comes, but by the time this is fired, the selection has already "snapped" to the nearest even hour, even if the click itself is in the latter half of the hour. All the `event...` callbacks are for after the event has already been selected, not while it's in the process of being selected. I suspect I may be out of luck with the current version of FullCalendar for both my issues. I agree - I don't want to get into monkey patching. Thanks anyway. -Lorill

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not sure, sadly, wish I could help. Searching around SO for fullcalendar related stuff seems to confirm that it may not be possible. Hopefully someone else with more experience can help. I'd encourage you to keep trying to find a solution, and if you ever figure it out, go ahead and post it as an answer here. Also, as you investigate the problem, if you find more info that is relevant, go ahead and edit the question and add that stuff in; it may help your question get some more visibility (just don't do massive numbers of useless edits, the moderators don't like that). Best of luck.

Comment: Regarding the dynamically changing options, this guy says no: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13449264/877472

Comment: The dynamic updating of options has been on the radar as a feature request for some time now: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293&q=windowresize&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: I added a new feature request to FullCalendar here to separate out the selection duration functionality from the snapMinutes functionality: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2018

Comment: I would still like this issue to be solved properly, but have implemented a workaround where if a user selects less than the desired duration, it alerts them that the duration isn't valid and de-selects what they just selected. Not ideal but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood Your issue correctly You could overwrite dayClick method (see docs), and inside made own selection with fullcalendar select method (see docs again). 
U could use 'date' argument of dayClick as stat time for selection, and obtain end time by adding 1h.
Effect of the above would be that on click on specified date u would get selection from clicked cell with length of 1 hour. 
Hope this will help, let me know if u need more specific advice (i've spend a lot time recently struggling with that kind of issues in fullcalendar)

Comment: Hi 4rlekin, I don't think this will work. The dayClick callback only gets fired upon release of the mouse, and also only if a selection hasn't been made (ie: it gets fired if it's a click and release within one slot, but if you click and drag to make a selection and release the mouse in a different slot, dayClick doesn't fire). I tried this in my fiddle above and confirmed this.