# In fullCalendar change slotDuration without page reloading

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar I need without page reloading to change `slotDuration` parameter depending on other conditions:

I do in one case

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'slotDuration', '00:15:00');
```

and in other case

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'slotDuration', '00:30:00');
```

But looks like it does not work, as I always see fullcalendar with `slotDuration=30` (2 slots) minutes, as it was called when initialized.

If there is a way for this?

Answer (score 7):

Now, you can set `dynamically` **without** *destorying* the `calendar`.

```
$('#cc-calendar')
  .fullCalendar('option','slotDuration','00:10:00');
```

Here, we work with the `Dynamically get/set Options` feature of `fullcalendar`.

For more info, check out : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/

Good Luck.

Comment: Option to do that was introduced in version 2.9.0. More info in [this thread on github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/564). And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38299511/2941313) by fullcalendar author.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017325/jquery-full-calendar-edit-calendar-properties-after-initialization), fullCalendar only allow change some properties after initialization. You don't need to reload the page, but destroy and init is required.

So:

```
var calendarOptions = {
    defaultView: 'month', 
    editable: true,
    slotDuration: '00:45:00', 
    (...)
}
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(calendarOptions); //Init

//And when you need to update any property

calendarOptions.slotDuration = '00:15:00';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(calendarOptions);
```