# fullCalendar/ui-calendar how to change the config and recreate a calendar?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui

What I want to do is to change the slotMinutes dynamic, I get the new slotMinutes and change in the config but I couldn't recreate the calendar with he new config.

I have tried 
$scope.calendar.fullCalendar('destroy');
$scope.calendar.fullCalendar('render');

I can destroy the calendar but cannot recreate it.

Any idea what should I do ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angularjs, but perhaps this similar question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432014/how-can-i-set-fullcalendar-options-dynamically

Comment: @scottysmalls Thanks. The answer in the question helps.